# Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime - How to get call information such as the history of incoming and outgoing calls?

Tags: c#, c++, runtime, windows-phone-8.1

Is there any way for getting incoming and outgoing calls log in Windows Phone Runtime 8.1?

I need to build an app that runs in background and saves calls log in the database.

If it's not possible in C#, is it possible to be done in C++?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with the current SDK, it does not matter if you use C# or C++.